How do I use Smartsheet connector in Power Apps?

How do I use Smartsheet connector to Insert Row in specific Sheet?
Documentation is quite poor and don't know how to pass values properly.
Code that I tried is below. How do I fix it to make to make it work?
Smartsheet.InsertRow(
    "192045464213123";
    {
        [
            {
                "columnId": 4266183311445892,
                "value": "TEST",
                "displayValue": "TEST"
            }
        ]
    }
)

